# PHP 7 return type inheritance

Tags: php, oop, generics, return-type

I've implemented the repository pattern in my project without too many issues. To avoid repeating myself, I have implemented an `abstract` repository class that all of my repositories extend. Each repository has its own `interface` that it must implement.

I have code similar to the following, which works fine:

```
class Model {}

class User extends Model {}

abstract class AbstractRepository
{
    protected $model;

    public function find($id)
    {
        $class = $this->model;

        return new $class();
    }
}

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find($id);
}

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $model = User::class;
}
```

I want to start using return type declarations in my code, having upgraded to PHP 7.1. So I added a `?Model` return type to the `find` method in my `AbstractRepository` and a `?User` return type to the `UserRepositoryInterface`.

```
class Model {}

class User extends Model {}

abstract class AbstractRepository
{
    protected $model;

    public function find($id): ?Model
    {
        $class = $this->model;

        return new $class();
    }
}

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find($id): ?User;
}

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $model = User::class;
}
```

Now, PHP complains that the declarations are incompatible, which I kind of expected.

> Fatal error: Declaration of AbstractRepository::find($id) must be compatible with AbstractRepositoryInterface::find($id): ?Model in /Users/jonathon/Desktop/test.php on line 21

In another language, such as Java I would have considered using Generics to implement the repository, which would allow me to use the generic type in the method signatures.

Is it possible to get this working so that:

- I have an interface and implementation for each repository
- I have an abstract class that is extended by each of my repositories, which does the majority of the work.
- I can continue using PHP 7's return type declarations, specifying a different return type for each different repository (e.g. `?User` for `UserRepositoryInterface` and `?Product` for `ProductRepositoryInterface`)?

The way I see it now, I have a few options:

- Don't bother using return types.
- Change all the return type declarations to be `?Model` which all of my models extend.
- Repeat myself, getting rid of the abstract class

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, I believe this is about overriding the return type on an abstract function? This is now possible in PHP 7.2 which was released earlier this month.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea I can't get it tho, https://3v4l.org/5PlP0 <-- change the return type of the latter class, it throws error. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Thanks for your answer. I've just installed PHP 7.2 locally and tried to run the code above. I've just seen the same error. However, the changes introduced do look promising and my immediate reaction was "that's it!". Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm hitting this issue as well. Seems crazily inconsistent with how argument type hints work. Also just upgraded to `7.2.2` and I'm still seeing the same error - described my situation here: https://3v4l.org/PnIAZ  - and my current work around here (using docblocks) https://3v4l.org/D6HAu

Comment: I just hit the same problem. Just by obeying OOPs inheritance rules this should work though, right? Any repo which inherits from the abstract will return a type via the find-method that is an extension of the abstracts repo find-method return type. Thus it would fulfill the contract. Every "User" suffices as a "Model" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are slight design flaws in the way you organize these repositories, without which the problem disappears.

> So I added a ?Model return type to the find method in my AbstractRepository and a ?User return type to the UserRepositoryInterface.

Why the change of type? A User is supposed to be a Model, just use Model as type hint.

> To avoid repeating myself, I have implemented an abstract repository class that all of my repositories extend. Each repository has its own interface that it must implement.

Having a one to one interface : concrete class ratio is a code smell, that's not what interfaces are *for*. It seems what you are really looking for is a Repository interface:

```
interface Repository
{
    public function find($id): Model;
}
```

That the abstract repository implements:

```
abstract class AbstractRepository implements Repository
{
    protected $model;

    public function find($id): Model
    {
        $class = $this->model;

        return new $class();
    }
}
```

So that a UserRepository can extend it (no need to implement it as the abstract already implements it). Since the `$model` property is already defined, it's a better practice to assign the value in the constructor.

```
class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = User::class;
    }
}
```

No more problem with type hints.

---

Opinions follow. I dislike inheritance. I find it's the surest and fastest way towards poor objects relations. I would just skip the abstract class altogether and get each repositories to implement the Repository interface. In practice, the find functions of repositories differ all the time, so we'd need to overwrite them in the concrete classes anyway.

```
interface Repository
{
    public function find($id): Model;
}


class UserRepository implements Repository
{
    public function find($id): Model
    {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Last nitty picking: Model is a poor name. It might rather be Entity. Model in MVC refers to the Model *layer*, in which we can find entities, services, mappers. More reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/576767).

Comment: I would have to disagree that having a one to one interface - class is a code smell. The reason I have a one interface with a one concrete class is so I can depend upon abstractions, not concretions as recommended in the dependency inversion principle (SOLI**D**). I'd be interested in why you think so, though? You are definitely correct that a `User` is a `Model`, however by defining `Model` as the return type, anything that is a model (A `Product`, `Category`) could be returned. This is why I want to constrain that only instances of `User` should be returned from such methods.

Comment: Also, I do agree that Model is a poor choice of name and that Entity is better. I usually go for Entity, however Model is the convention of the framework I'm using and the code provided is simply to illustrate a point.